# Change dropdown-menu to button when it only contains one value

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a database in Moodle (Learning management system) which generates a bootstrap table.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Table]

The last row contains a dropdown-menu. When it is your own entry you are able to view, edit or delete the entry (three values to select from):

[image: Dropdown for own entry]

For other users entries you can only view the entry (only one value to select from) so the dropdown-menu isn't really needed:

[image: Dropdown for other entries]

**How can I change the dropdown-menu for other entries to a button while keeping the dropdown-menu for own entries?**

The button should also say "Mehr" but only be a link to the "view.php" page.
I can only use CSS or Javascript but I don't know JS. I can give the dropdown-menu an own class but only for all dropdown-menus.

This is the code of two dropdown-menus (#1 from own entry and #2 from other entry):

```
<div class="dropdown" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1676893448131_33"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">Mehr</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="will-change: transform;">
        <div class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://[...]/mod/data/view.php?d=53&amp;rid=1974"><i
                    class="icon fa fa-search-plus fa-fw " title="Einzelansicht" role="img"
                    aria-label="Einzelansicht"></i></a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-item"><a
                href="https://[...]/mod/data/edit.php?d=53&amp;rid=1974&amp;sesskey=QmOlQH4lg5"><i
                    class="icon fa fa-cog fa-fw " title="Bearbeiten" role="img" aria-label="Bearbeiten"></i></a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-item"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-item"><a
                href="https://[...]/mod/data/view.php?d=53&amp;delete=1974&amp;sesskey=QmOlQH4lg5"><i
                    class="icon fa fa-trash fa-fw " title="Löschen" role="img" aria-label="Löschen"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mehr</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://[...]/mod/data/view.php?d=53&amp;rid=1973"><i
                    class="icon fa fa-search-plus fa-fw " title="Einzelansicht" role="img"
                    aria-label="Einzelansicht"></i></a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-item"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-item"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm basically looking for some Javascript to do something like this:
Wenn dropdown-menu only containts one dropdown-item then change dropdown-menu to a button with content of href with aria label "Einzelansicht" (View).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Mehr</button>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://[...]/mod/data/view.php?d=53&amp;rid=1973" role="button">Link</a>
```

Can anyone help me out with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to detect the quantity of elements inside the dropdown and personalize them.

Add this script to your code:

```
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu'); // All drop down menus

// Loop through the drop down menus
dropdowns.forEach(function(dropdown) {
  
  let numItems = dropdown.length; // Number of items in the drop down
  
  // Conditionally render the appropriate element
  if (numItems === 1) {

    // Render your button
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = 'Mehr'; // Add the text to the button
    button.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Einzelansicht'); // Your aria-label
    button.setAttribute('href', dropdown.querySelector('a').href); // the href attr
    dropdown.parentNode.replaceChild(button, dropdown);

  }
});
```

This will render a button if the dropdown only has one item. It will also add the attributes you are looking to add to the button.

Otherwise it will leave it as it is, showing the current dropdown.

Comment: Thanks this looks exactly like what I need. It doesn't work yet though. I tried to use `let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu'); // All drop down menus

// Loop through the drop down menus
dropdowns.forEach(function(dropdown) {
  
  let numItems = dropdown.length; // Number of items in the drop down
  
  // Conditionally render the appropriate element
  if (numItems === 1) {

    alert("I am an alert box!");

  }
});` but this doesnt work either. Using only `alert("I am an alert box!");` works so it must be able to execute JS code.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't find the dropdown-menus because they all have more items even though they are just empty?

Comment: Send the error messages that appears in your terminal with this js

Comment: I only get this error but I also get this error without your code: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
    sph_message https://[...]/mod/data/view.php?d=53:55`